# How can write a MySQL query to have 2 group by, max conditions?

Tags: mysql, group-by, query-optimization

This is my table:

```
create table program_versions
(
    id                  int auto_increment primary key,
    program_id          int,
    version             smallint,
    start_date          datetime,
    constraint uniq_contraint unique (program_id, version),
    index idx_pi_sd (program_id, start_date)
)
```

This is the SELECT query in question:

```
SELECT 
    pv.program_id,
    max(pv.version) as version,
    pv.start_date
FROM program_versions pv 
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
        program_id,
        max(start_date) recent_date
    FROM program_versions
    WHERE start_date <= NOW()
    GROUP BY program_id 
    ) pv_temp 
        ON pv.program_id = pv_temp.program_id
        AND pv.start_date = pv_temp.recent_date
GROUP BY pv.program_id, pv.start_date;
```

The table has around 1M rows.
When the MySQL version was 5.6, the query was fined (run within expected time). However, when the server was upgraded to 5.7, this query started executing very slow (~4min)

There is no way for me to change the MySQL server version, so I need to find another way to optimize this query.
Any suggestions/recommendations will be appreciated

I tried to create a temporary table instead of sub-query, but I still need to run the outer GROUP BY, which is extremely slow

**UPDATE**

**SELECT VERSION()**

```
5.7.41-log
```

**SHOW CREATE TABLE program_versions**

```
CREATE TABLE `program_versions` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `program_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `version` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `start_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `uniq_contraint` (`program_id`,`version`),
  KEY `idx_pi_sd` (`program_id`,`start_date`),
  KEY `idx_pi_sd_vs` (`program_id`,`start_date`,`version`),
  KEY `idx_sd` (`start_date`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3014611 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
```

**ANALYZE TABLE program_versions;**

```
+---------------------------+-------+--------+--------+
|Table                      |Op     |Msg_type|Msg_text|
+---------------------------+-------+--------+--------+
|local_test.program_versions|analyze|status  |OK      |
+---------------------------+-------+--------+--------+
```

**SHOW INDEXES FROM program_versions;**

```
+----------------+----------+--------------+------------+-----------+---------+-----------+--------+------+----+----------+-------+-------------+
|Table           |Non_unique|Key_name      |Seq_in_index|Column_name|Collation|Cardinality|Sub_part|Packed|Null|Index_type|Comment|Index_comment|
+----------------+----------+--------------+------------+-----------+---------+-----------+--------+------+----+----------+-------+-------------+
|program_versions|0         |PRIMARY       |1           |id         |A        |2994640    |null    |null  |    |BTREE     |       |             |
|program_versions|0         |uniq_contraint|1           |program_id |A        |1498041    |null    |null  |YES |BTREE     |       |             |
|program_versions|0         |uniq_contraint|2           |version    |A        |2994640    |null    |null  |YES |BTREE     |       |             |
|program_versions|1         |idx_pi_sd     |1           |program_id |A        |1499264    |null    |null  |YES |BTREE     |       |             |
|program_versions|1         |idx_pi_sd     |2           |start_date |A        |1499264    |null    |null  |YES |BTREE     |       |             |
|program_versions|1         |idx_pi_sd_vs  |1           |program_id |A        |1498952    |null    |null  |YES |BTREE     |       |             |
|program_versions|1         |idx_pi_sd_vs  |2           |start_date |A        |1498952    |null    |null  |YES |BTREE     |       |             |
|program_versions|1         |idx_pi_sd_vs  |3           |version    |A        |2994640    |null    |null  |YES |BTREE     |       |             |
|program_versions|1         |idx_sd        |1           |start_date |A        |124        |null    |null  |YES |BTREE     |       |             |
+----------------+----------+--------------+------------+-----------+---------+-----------+--------+------+----+----------+-------+-------------+
```

**EXPLAIN SELECT...**

```
+--+-----------+----------------+----------+-----+--------------------------------------------+------------+-------+--------------------------------------+-------+--------+--------------------------------------------+
|id|select_type|table           |partitions|type |possible_keys                               |key         |key_len|ref                                   |rows   |filtered|Extra                                       |
+--+-----------+----------------+----------+-----+--------------------------------------------+------------+-------+--------------------------------------+-------+--------+--------------------------------------------+
|1 |PRIMARY    |<derived2>      |null      |ALL  |null                                        |null        |null   |null                                  |1497320|100     |Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort|
|1 |PRIMARY    |pv              |null      |ref  |uniq_contraint,idx_pi_sd,idx_pi_sd_vs,idx_sd|idx_pi_sd_vs|11     |pv_temp.program_id,pv_temp.recent_date|1      |100     |Using index                                 |
|2 |DERIVED    |program_versions|null      |index|uniq_contraint,idx_pi_sd,idx_pi_sd_vs,idx_sd|idx_pi_sd   |11     |null                                  |2994640|50      |Using where; Using index                    |
+--+-----------+----------------+----------+-----+--------------------------------------------+------------+-------+--------------------------------------+-------+--------+--------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: What version of MySQL 5.7 are you running (`SELECT VERSION();`)? Please add the full output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE program_versions` to your question, execute `ANALYZE TABLE program_versions;` and then add output from `SHOW INDEXES FROM program_versions;` and `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` for the full query and just the subquery, and add the results to your question.

Comment: @user1191247 Added the results of those queries

Comment: Those stats suggest your table has ~3M rows and that this result set is ~1.5M rows. Is that correct? How long does the subquery take to execute and how many rows does it return? What does _"within expected time"_ mean? Please quantify.

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT 
    pv.program_id,
    MAX(pv.version) AS version,
    pv.start_date
FROM program_versions pv 
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT program_id, MAX(start_date) AS recent_date
    FROM program_versions
    WHERE start_date <= NOW()
    GROUP BY program_id
) pv_temp ON pv.program_id = pv_temp.program_id
          AND pv.start_date = pv_temp.recent_date
GROUP BY pv.program_id, pv.start_date;
```

The query performance can be increased by using Indexing and subquery

```
CREATE INDEX idx_start_date ON program_versions(start_date);
```

Comment: The suggested index would be ignored, as the existing index `idx_pi_sd (program_id, start_date)` supports OP's query nicely.